# Error: Expected resource of type layout... for ColorRes?

Tags: android, annotations, attributes

So I'm getting this error when I do a lint check:

```
Error: Expected resource of type layout [ResourceType]
final EditTimeAdapter adapter = new EditTimeAdapter(getContext(), options, textColor); 
(Squiggly line under textColor)
```

Here's the code it is complaining about:

```
 public void setTextColor(@ColorRes int textColor) {
   final EditTimeAdapter adapter = new EditTimeAdapter(getContext(), options, textColor);
```

And the constructor for EditTimeAdapter:

```
public EditTimeAdapter(Context context, List<LocalTime> objects, @ColorRes int color) {
        super(context, objects);
        this.color = color;
    }
```

So uhm from my understanding: 1) this should be reporting an error about "color" and not "layout", and 2) this shouldn't even be an error. Anyone know what could be up?

Comment: How is `textColor` declared? It may be that it expects something of the form `R.color.something` as the argument (and not a color value). As for the error message, that might just be a typo.

Comment: The textColor is declared in the parameter list as shown above. There's a few more levels of methods with parameters with annotations of @ColorRes in a chain and at the top a R.color.* is used. I can confirm that not using a color I get another error message that states a color, hence why I think the error message is not a typo.